# Read from file Common Lisp

Tags: file, lisp, common-lisp

I need to read from a file but I'm having some issues with the code. I've to read i file like this:

```
1.0 4.5
4.555 6.43
4.0 5
.....
6 3
```

2 numbers per line separated by `#\Space` or `#\Tab` (in the file I can have a big number of lines). The function read must return a list like this:

```
((1.0 4.5)(4.555 6.43)(4.0 5)...(6 3))
```

I've tried using `with-open-file`, `read-line` and recursion but i'm having issues handling streams etc. to put those element in the list in the right way

```
(with-open-file (in "foo.lisp"
            :direction :input
            :if-does-not-exist :error)
(myread in))

(defun myread (filename)
(let ((e (read-line filename nil ’eof))))

???

(cons (;;;numbers of current line;;;)(myread (filename)))
```

How can I do that? thanks

Answer (score 6):

The **usual idiom** is

```
(defun read-file-as-lines (filename)
  "Read file into a list of lines."
  (with-open-file (in filename)
    (loop for line = (read-line in nil nil)
      while line
      collect line)))

(defun line-as-list (line)
  "Read all objects from the line as a list."
  (read-from-string (concatenate 'string "(" line ")")))

(mapcar #'line-as-list (read-file-as-lines "mydata"))
```

If you are concerned with memory use, you can use [`map-into`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map_in.htm) instead of [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) or even pass `line-as-list` as an argument to `read-file-as-lines`.

**Required reading**:

- [`with-open-file`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_open.htm)
- [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm)
- [`read-from-string`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_fro.htm)
- [`concatenate`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_concat.htm)

**Exercise**: use `loop` in `line-as-list` instead of prepending and appending parenthesis.
This way you can control how many objects you read and handle comments &c.

**Solution**: [`string-tokens`](https://sourceforge.net/p/clocc/hg/ci/default/tree/src/port/ext.lisp#l137).